# Replace whole string in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a .c file where I want to replace all occurrences of `/*abc*/` with `xyz`. How do I do that in Vim?

Comment: in vim type `:help :substitute` it will show you some commands. The basic command is like this `:%s/foo/bar/g`

Comment: open in vim and command is ":%s/abc/xyz/g" it will replace all, so better to use ":%s/abc/xyx/gc"  this will find and ask for replace or not. you can press Y to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Vim allows you to use other characters than `/` when substituting, so e.g. `:%s#/abc/#xyz#g` makes it easier when you have `/` as part of the pattern you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace "`/*abc*/`" with "`xyz`", go to command mode and:

```
:%s/\/\*abc\*\//xyz/g
```

Note that "`/`" and "`*`" must be escaped.